# É possivel chamar membros de uma class do tipo dynamic como uma string?

Tags: c#, variáveis, dynamic

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        dynamic stud = new Student();
        Console.WriteLine(stud.Name);
        
    }
}

public class Student
{
    public string Name = "John";
}
```

> Output John

Existe alguma forma de conseguir o mesmo resultado chamado o membro como uma string sem modificar a class, algo do tipo:

```
Console.WriteLine(stud["Name"]);
```

Comment: como duvida em si seria possivel, mas nem ao menos Name é uma property, pode fazer isso por reflexion, mas sendo um membro publico que não é property não se pode usar o método `GetProperty` que resolveria isso fácil, precisa ir mais fundo no reflexion para ler a variável ... já como código em si é absolutamente sem sentido criar um `dynamic` a partir de um tipo conhecido (Student), algo como `var stud = new Student()` seria o melhor, fora que expor uma variável pública não é uma boa abordagem, uma propriedade ficaria melhor ai.

Comment: @RicardoPontual este foi apenas um exemplo ilustrativo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como resposta, não levando em consideração o código em si, pode ser feito por reflexion caso `Name` seja uma propriedade:

```
var name = stud
          .GetType()
          .GetProperty("Name")  // Só funciona com properties
          .GetValue(stud, null);
```

No caso de ser uma variável, uma outra possibilidade (uma gambiarra na verdade, apenas para ilustrar) seria usar um serializer, como o `Newtonsoft.Json` para acessar como se fosse um key de um dicionário:

```
var serializado =  Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stud);
var objeto = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serializado);
var name = objeto["Name"];
```

Aqui os dois exemplos funcionando: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NAPxlV